# Is there an Official Android development environment image on Docker?

Tags: android, docker

I tried searching for one , but there were too many to choose from. Is there an image that is considered official?

Comment: A docker development environment? Would that just contain ADB? Docker is for microservices, not full-blown development environments

Comment: @cricket_007 Docker is for whatever you intend to do with. And it is very useful to use docker images with development stacks ready to use for setting up continuous integration.

Comment: Google has not published any Android related Docker images to the best of my knowledge. That would be the only thing that would qualify as "official" IMHO. That being said, asking for off-site resources is considered to be off-topic here at Stack Overflow.